# Why won't this dao class autowire?

Tags: java, spring

Please look at the files below and tell me why the Dao will not autowire.  It autowires correctly when the same setter is put in a controller.  I put it in this class and it does not work.

Business Class

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticateUser {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityDAO securityDAO;

    public void setSecurityDAO(SecurityDAO securityDAO) {
        this.securityDAO = securityDAO;
    }

    protected void execute() {          
        User authenticatedUser = securityDAO.login(get_userName(),
                                                   get_password());     
    }
}
```

application-context.xml

```xml
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="myDataSource" 
    class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
      </property>
      <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname</value>
      </property>
      <property name="username">
        <value>un</value>
      </property>
      <property name="password">
        <value>pw</value>
      </property>
      <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" /> 
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
            <value>com.projectname.model.SecurityInfo</value>
            <value>com.projectname.model.User</value>
            <value>com.projectname.model.Post</value>
            <value>com.projectname.model.Article</value>
            <value>com.projectname.model.Address</value>
            </list>
        </property> 
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="mySecurityInfoDAO" class="com.projectname.dao.SecurityDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.projectname" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <value>/WEB-INF/messages/messages</value>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you show the name of the package where `AuthenticateUser` is in?

Comment: Or even better, can you confirm that the class `AuthenticateUser` is actually instantiated by spring?

Comment: "it does not work" is not helpful. Tell us what happens.

Comment: Hint: if you annotated a field with (@Autowired, @Ressoucce, @Inject) the injection goes directly in this field, but not through the setter.

Comment: To get the value to go through the setter, put the annotation on the setter and not the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Let my guess: `AuthenticatedUser` is a Domain Entity?**

Spring can only handle Spring Beans, and can only inject in Spring Beans.

If you have a class that is instantiated in a Pojo way by `new` (or loaded form the database by Hibernate/JPA,...) it does not become a Spring Bean.

But you can make even this Pojos become Spring Beans. You need 3 things:

- add [@Configurable](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) to the Entity
- turn on Spring Configurable support:
- enable AspectJ (AspectJ not Spring AOP) - compiletime or loadtime weaving. -- If you use compiletime weaving you need to use an AspectJ Compiler

@See:

- [Spring Reference: Chapter 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-atconfigurable)
- [Using Spring’s @Configurable in three easy steps](http://www.olivergierke.de/wordpress/2009/05/using-springs-configurable-in-three-easy-steps/)
- [Spring, Aspects, @Configurable and Compile Time Weaving using maven](http://www.chrissearle.org/node/285)

Comment: He's using component-scan to scan for classes annotated with the `@Component` annotation. When configured properly, this should be fine.

Comment: If you need elaborate injection, a class annotated with `@Configuration` can provide extra beans; just annotate the relevant factory methods with `@Bean`. Since that configuration class is also a component itself, you can inject its own configuration into it; this can be a really good solution to tricky injection problems.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Is there any way to make Hibernate a bean factory?

Comment: @M Platvoet: Thats why I started with: "Let my guess: AuthenticatedUser is a Domain Entity?" and then explained why it does not work per default.

Comment: Don't know. I handle my (relatively trivial) persistence problems through JDO instead, because at the time I could figure that out in sufficient detail.