# Spring MVC With Hibernate; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException When getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am Getting this error  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/org] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.aquicktrack.controller.RegistrationDao.insertCustomer(RegistrationDao.java:31)
    at com.aquicktrack.org.StratUpController.getRegistration(StratUpController.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My Spring Configuration File

```
<!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost 
        port 3306 with username root and blank password. Change below if it's not 
        the case -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/study" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.aquicktrack.com.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

and My Java Code

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @Transactional
    public void insertCustomer()
    {
        Registration registration = new Registration();
        registration.setFullname("Ashish Srivastava");
        registration.setEmail("Ashish");
        registration.setIsRegister("0");
        registration.setPhone("xxxxxxxxxx");
        registration.setStatus("0");
        registration.setTime("1234567890");
        registration.setVehicle("12");
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(registration);
        logger.info("Person saved successfully, Registration Details="+registration);
    }
```

When i want get current session from session factory class it throw it

Comment: This one Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

Comment: Is the SessionFactory injected correctly?

Comment: actually i am new in Spring MVC and Hibernate i am not getting how can do this bt in console Hibernate Run correctly with my entity class create database

Comment: Let me guess in your controller you do `new RegistrationDao()` instead of using the spring managed instance.

Comment: yes i am creating a instance of this class and call the method using object

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments:

> Let me guess in your controller you do new RegistrationDao() instead
>   of using the spring managed instance. – M. Deinum

---

> yes i am creating a instance of this class and call the method using
>   object – Ashish Srivastava

---

The problem is that Spring will only inject in Spring Managed Beans*. When you create a object with `new` then it is NOT a Spring Managed Bean!

So add `@Repository` Annotation to your DAO, and let the DAO injected into your controller by adding a filed with `@Autowird` annotation, and then use it instead of `new DAO`!

```
@Repository
public class YourDAO{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    ...

    @Transactional
    public void insertCustomer(){...}
}

@Controller
public class YourController{
    @Autowired
    private YourDao yourDao;

    ... {
       this.yourDao.insertCustomer();
    }
}
```

**[Except when `@Configurable` is used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6421900/280244)*

Comment: Getting this error could not autowire field: com.aquicktrack.controller.RegistrationDao com.aquicktrack.org.StratUpController.registrationdoa; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.aquicktrack.controller.RegistrationDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: You need configure Spring that its component scan also scan the package containing YourDAO.

Comment: Its Go To Next Step But Now I am Getting this error 

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

Comment: New problem, new question: this is not related to this question anymore, so please ask a new one, and post the relevant code.